# QueryDsl is fetching all record upon join and not considering ON condition

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to fetch record based on join , but it is fetching matched as well unmatched entity .

Database - MySQL

Data Model -

[image]

Query -

```
 ClassDetail classDetail = jpaQueryFactory
        .selectFrom(CLASS_DETAIL).distinct()
        .leftJoin(CLASS_DETAIL.students,STUDENT)
        .on(CLASS_DETAIL.eq(CLASS_DETAIL))
        .leftJoin(STUDENT.transactions,TRANSACTION)
        .on(TRANSACTION.type.eq(PayTypeEnum.FEES.name()))
        .where(CLASS_DETAIL.id.eq(classId))
        .fetchOne();
```

ClassDetail have many-to-many bidirectional association with STUDENT, and STUDENT have one-to-many bidirectional association with TRANSACTION.

I am doing lazy load and using hibernate 5.6.15 FINAL.

ClassDetail have STUDENT list as expected, but when I traverse to STUDENT, and do getClassDetail(), it gives me all classes that student belongs to and not considering the `ON` condition of query. Same Happening with transaction, I expect only the `FEES` type transaction to be fetched, but it fetches all other as well in the list.

Attaching screenshot .

TRANSACTION ENTITY -

[image]

STUDENT ENTITY -

[image]

RESULTSET -

[image]

Lazy Load is firing the default query and `ON` condition is not included.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with what Hibernate supports. If you want to filter a fetched association, then you will have to use a Hibernate filter i.e. `@Filter`. Join fetching a collection and filtering it might lead to data loss, because on data changes, Hibernate will synchronize the collection contents with the table again and if that doesn't respect the same filter, you will loose data. A `ON` clause for a fetch join can not be supported, which is why you need to use Hibernate filters.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5 and above don't support on clause, and hence it was not working. We have to use @Filter or @Where annotations to achieve this.